# Publish Data From WSO2 ESB to WSO2 DAS

Tags: rest, soap, wso2-das, wso2-esb

Is there any way to publish multiple services data from WSO2 ESB to WSO2 DAS at one time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create multiple streams with different attributes in DAS. Then for each stream you can add soap receivers which soap endpoints can be used to send data from ESB. Please refer [DAS documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Understanding+Event+Streams+and+Event+Tables) for more information.